# Is it possible to have the alarm sound in Max Power saving Mode?

Tags: samsung, alarm, power-options, samsung-galaxy-a3

My Samsung A3 has a function called Max Power Saving Mode which I assume is Samsung's version of Ultra Power Saving mode. I find it very helpful sometimes but when this mode alarms dont go off. Is there any way to allow alarms ( set in the clock app) to go off in this mode? I've checked through the settings for this mode and I can't find anything which allows it. I've searched the web and I couldn't fine anything about this though I did find some stuff on UPSM but the settings didn't seem to match.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered the answer literally 1 minute after asking the question so I thought I'd answer it myself in case it's of any advantage to anyone else.

There's a very simple ( but quite odd in my opinion ) solution to this. Simply adding the clock app to the the shortcut screen of Max Power Saving Mode ( by clicking one of the plus signs ) solves the issue completely.

**With the shortcut added - the alarm sounds. Without it - silence.**

Comment: This works because only apps on the home screen of max battery saver are kept on. All others are turned off to save battery life.